# C# Linq 2 Dimensional List Filter

Tags: c#, list, linq

Edit - Figuered this out thanks to @Monofuse:

```html
List<List<int>> list1,
list2,
list2_flattened = list2.SelectMany(x => x).ToList(); // 1d list

list1 = list1.Select(x => x.Where(y => !list2_flattened.Contains(y)).ToList()).ToList(); // 2d list (definitely not the most efficient function, but my list is constrained to a size of about 20)
```

Given the 2 lists:

```csharp
List<List<int>> list1;
List<List<int>> list2;
```

How would you filter the items in List1, such that you end up with items that **don't** exist in list2?

**forgot to mention: list1 must keep the original structure (that is List<List>, so SelectMany isn't an option)**

**I'm looking for a linq solution**

Thanks!

Comment: Flatten both lists with SelectMany and use Except then.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your current code attempt?

Comment: could you add a example for a positive and a negative match? @rkrahl does the order matter?

Comment: You have 2 sets of sets, what is the definition of "*don't exist*" ?

Comment: @TheGeneral I meant the int's themselves. No item in list1's lists can exist in list2's lists

Comment: Flatten list 2 and then use Select(l => l.Except(flat).ToList()).ToList()

Comment: `List1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}` and `List2 = {{1,3},{6,5,4}}` what is the expected result ?

Comment: Anyway, I am glad you have got your answer, but just know the question was kind of atrocious and turned into a guessing game. Try to be very specific when you are asking a question like this

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll provide a clear example next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you right, and you want to *exclude* `list2` `int` values from `list1` you can put

```
 var result = list1
   .Select(list => list
     .Where(item => !list2
       .SelectMany(dropList => dropList)
       .Any(drop => drop == item))
     .ToList())
   .ToList();
```

For instance

```
  List<List<int>> list1 = new List<List<int>>() {
    new List<int>() { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4},
    new List<int>() { 2,},
    new List<int>() { 5, 6,}
  };

  // We should remove 2, 5, 3 whenever they appear in list1
  List<List<int>> list2 = new List<List<int>>() {
    new List<int>() { 2, 5},
    new List<int>() { 3, 3},
  };

  var result = list1
   .Select(list => list
     .Where(item => !list2
       .SelectMany(dropList => dropList)
       .Any(drop => drop == item))
     .ToList())
   .ToList();

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(line => $"[{string.Join(", ", line)}]"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
[1, 4, 4]
[]
[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you wanted to remove list1 lists where there is no longer anything in it. Also wasn't sure if you wanted to check that every item in a sublist matches all of a sublist of list2.

```
var list1 = new List<List<int>>();
var list2 = new List<List<int>>();
var flatList2 = list2.SelectMany(l2 => l2).Distinct();

var result = list1
    .Select(o => o
        .Where(inner => !flatList2.Contains(inner)))
    .Where(o => o.Any());
```

The below one is exactly the same, it just has different variable names. I think it might help people understand a little more. As we are dealing with a two dimensional array, I always find it a little easier to think of it like a table.

```
var table = new List<List<int>>();
var table2 = new List<List<int>>();
var distinctColumns = table2.SelectMany(row => row).Distinct();

var result = table
    .Select(row => row
        .Where(column => !distinctColumns.Contains(column)))
    .Where(row => row.Any());
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great!

To clarify - I'm only interested in filterring our the matching ints (so if any item inside list1 exists in any of the lists inside list2 -> that item will be excluded)

Also, wouldn't it be better to flatten list2 once (before you filter items), instead of doing it for every inner item?

Comment: "list2.SelectMany(l2 => l2)" - this can be declared above to not do this action on each iteration.

Comment: We can also distinct() to remove duplicate values from the flat version